# Why is my voltage disapearing from esp32 to RJ45 connector?

Tags: circuit-design, uart, esp32, rs485

I am working on a project where I am sending data from an ESP32 through an RJ45 cable to a DMX decoder.  As far as I can tell my wiring is correct, however, I do not appear to be getting the signal to the decoder.

[image]

**EDIT** Schematic was updated per suggestions in the comment sections.  The dotted lines are to be ignored as they go to other components and traces not associated with this issue.

Currently, my ESP32 is being powered via a USB cable from my computer, and the MAX345 is being powered from a 12v bench power supply.  I do have a regulator that steps it down to 5v which I have verified.

My first idea was to start looking at the voltages that I am getting between the ESP32 and my RJ45 connector.  When the signal leaves the ESP32 it is around 3.3v, however, when it gets to the RJ45 connector it is just over 0 at .115 on both the A & B pins.

My first thought was the DE pin on my MAX345.  I know that to send data it has be to high, which I tied to the 3v3 on my ESP32.  However, when I hook up my multimeter to it, I am getting just shy of 5v.  Should I be feeding 3v3 to the DE pin, why would my ESP32 be outputting 5v instead of 3v3?

This could also very well be a software issue, but before I start down that rabbit hole I wanted to check for wiring issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can I suggest you take a moment to read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/28251/173919 ... confusing diagrams lead to confusing circuits and confusing debugging.  What do your dotted lines represent?  What do the red and green mean?  is the ground of the CPU connected to the other ground of the voltage reg?  The 5V?

Comment: Specifically: if your `GND` of CPU isn't connected to `GND` of MAX3485, then the MAX3485 won't see HIGH on `DE`, and so the output won't be enabled, and so you'll see nothing/noise on `A` and `B`.  I note that diagram says you're powering "MAX3485" from 5V, but it has a 3.0 to 3.6 V range ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX3483-MAX3491.pdf))

Comment: @jonathanjo thank you for the feedback.  I will update the scematic to make it more clear.  Your second comment makes sense, as the `GND` of the MAX3485 is connected to ground from my voltage regulator.  I also didn't notice/think about the high `VCC` for the MAX3485.

Comment: That diagram is incomprehensible and probably incomplete (the voltage regulator is powering nothing?).  Draw a neater one with all of the connections.  You'll probably find the problem in the process.

Comment: @user1850479 You are correct that the diagram is incomplete.  The final design will have an external 12v power supply feeding my board, which is then brought down with the voltage regulator.  However, in trying to troubleshoot this problem, I have broken it down to the bare essentials and will build it back up once I isolate the issue.  If a full schematic would help, I can provide it; I was just trying to make it easier to read and focus on the problem.
Outside of being incomplete, what is incomprehensible about it?

Comment: The standard method for debugging hardware is the same as anything else: divide and conquer.  So: try getting your MAX3485 to work solely with direct connections to 3.3V and GND.  (Ie, `DE` to 3V3 and set `D` to `GND` or 3V3.  You should see differential signals on `A` and `B`.  If you don't, chip is faulty.  Once you have that working, measure the GPIO from the CPU, is it what you expect?  If not, some other fault.  Once the two sides are both working, connect them.

Comment: "what is incomprehensible about it?" .. what do the colours mean, what do dashes mean? Are they connections or not?   Regulator seems to be doing nothing.  Everything is sideways, lines cross anywhere, everything is jagged,   Where is 5V connected?    Honestly, a photo of a breadboard would be better.  What did you draw it with?

Comment: Is the RS-485 "block" in the drawing a chip or a module - impossible to tell. What type it is, as there reads MAX345 and MAX3485? If dotted lines are to be ignored, you have no common ground between connector and RS-485 driver. If there is 5V on DE pin, there must be a wiring mistake somewhere and both 3.3V blocks, the ESP and RS485 driver may be damaged/burnt and won't work.

Comment: Actually, which exact "RJ45 connector" you are using? Are you sure it is just a plain modular jack, or does it contain other parts inside it?